# Exception issue on vector reserve in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am unable to reserve the vector length while reading a large 100GB file. It worked for smaller file sizes upto 30GB sizes.

Following is the code:

```
#include<vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<float> v;
    v.reserve(73192550880); 
    return 0;
}
```

Following exception is shown in gcc compiler:

> Program returned: 139
> Program stderr
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
> what():  std::bad_alloc

Can someone please help on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that beuase  you are asking for a contiguous block of memroy thats > 100gb

Comment: you will have to get smart. Break it up into smaller peices. Use memory mapped file....

Comment: Buying a computer with 100+ GB of RAM is another option.

Comment: Does your system have 100gb of available virtual memory? Also check the value of [max_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size), even if you have enough memory your standard library may impose a limit

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 100GB+ of RAM on your physical machine to be able to allocate ***and*** use 100GB of memory. Our programs may be made up, but machine it runs on is real, and has real physical limits.

Overcomitting kernels may allow you to allocate more than what you physically have thanks to the nature of virtual memory, but the moment you touch it in any way beyond what's physically possible, your program will be terminated. It's best to never mess around with OOM Killer and only use what you actually need.

Average person has anywhere from 2GB to 64GB of RAM and 64GB is usually some workstation at your workplace because very few people actually need 64GB of RAM at home, and unless you're writing code for servers that were designed to deal with you abusing it like this, you will have to get smart about how you deal with data. In fact, average person expects you to use as little memory as possible to solve the problem you're solving. And you should have exact same mindset.

You have not told us anything about your data, so I cannot give you more than a generic answer, but there's at least 3 strategies depending on what you are doing:

1. Process data as you read it, this is only possible when each data point is independent and there's no other specific criteria for processing it; as an example, most `fread` (C library function for buffered reading, may be used by `fstream` in C++) implementations that I know of read in 4KiB chunks from physical disk to the userspace, meaning that you can process terabytes of data with as little as few megabytes of RAM. But it doesn't mean you have to go that low, make it configurable. Someone has a lot of free RAM and wants to process something faster? Sure, let them tell your program to use a way bigger buffer in gigabytes. That's already a lot better than expecting someone to buy 128GB of RAM.
2. Use memory mapping. On Linux and MacOS, it is documented in man pages `mmap(2)`, on Windows that would be [CreateFileMapping*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga). Now that you mapped it, it is as trivial as accessing it like any other 100GB  C-style pointer to data as if it were a contiguous array, your operating system's kernel will do all the work for you behind the scenes by reading and writing data directly between memory pages and your disk, and while it will be "slower" than 100GB vector, you need to remember that you cannot allocate a 100GB vector at all. Don't forget to unmap the file when you're done.
3. Use a database. Databases were designed for fast on-disk storage access with ability to sort, filter, map data and more coming along with it for free. Any SQL database works, but SQLite is a good choice if you only need a local database that will only ever be used by programs installed on the same system, and has an incredibly easy core [C API](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) that will solve most of your problems despite inherent complexity that databases have.

Comment: You don't need 100gb of ram, just 100gb of virtual memory space

Comment: @AlanBirtles You either need 100gb of ram, or 100gb of virtual memory space and a lot of time and patience. You may get away with just 100gb of virtual memory space in *some* usage scenarios.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. with a decent SSD and depending on the access pattern, swap space might not be that slow

Comment: @AlanBirtles and here I thought that marking "and" in ***bold cursive*** would prevent this stupid comment from appearing. Swap space is a completely separate thing and noone has a 100GB swap file, because at that point you may aswell learn how to memory map a file instead of abusing your disk for something worse than simply memory mapping your big file. Sure, you can do this, doesn't mean it's ever a good idea, which is why I'm not going to recommend people do terrible things.

Comment: @yotsugi it doesn't matter if you put it in bold or not, if your machine has swap space then it has more available memory than it has RAM, it might be slower but it is certainly possible to allocate **and** use more memory than will fit in your RAM. OOM killer wont kick in until the swap space **and** the RAM are full